# Not keeping the previous data in session array

Tags: express-session

I am working on an online food ordering project using MEAN full stack. On the server I am using an express session for persisting the data. I have declared an array session to store the array data in the session but it is not keeping the previous data -- it overwrites the existing value. Here is my code:

```
app.put('/addCart',function(req,res,next){

    db.collection('product',function(err,productCollection){

        var id = parseInt(req.body.id);


productCollection.findOne({_id:id},{},function(err, products){
            var cart = req.session.cart || [];  


    if(req.session.cart == null){ 

        req.session.cart = [{p_id: products._id, p_name: products.title, p_price: products.price,quantity:1}];
            }

             else{

        cart.push({p_id: products._id, p_name: products.title, p_price: products.price,quantity:1});
            }
                return res.json(req.session.cart);
            });
        });
    });
```

In the controller I am passing the id of each food item to the server.
Here is angular code:

```
    app.controller('FoodCartController' , function($rootScope,$scope, $http,$routeParams){
            $scope.addCart = function(food){
                $http.put('/addCart',{id:food._id}).then(function(response){
                console.log(response.data);
                $scope.carts = response.data;
        });
    });
```

Please help me sort out this problem.